# Numpy column titles NOT Record Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is I guess very simple, but it has frustrated me for the last hour or so... 
I want to use NORMAL numpy array with titles (not Record Array):
e.g. (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

```
x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('a','<f4'),('b','<f4')])
```

However I have a regular non column numpy array, e.g.

```
x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)])
```

and a list of names e.g.

```
names = ['a','b']
```

How do I combine both titled less x and names to a x with titles?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the `dtype` property of `x` as follows:

```
x.dtype = np.dtype([(n, x.dtype) for n in names])
```

This will update the dtype in place. If you need to change the dtype, you'll have to build a new array:

```
dtypes = ['<f4']*len(names)
y = np.array(x, dtype=zip(names, dtypes))
```

Comment: It better be x.dtype = np.dtype([(n, x.dtype) for n in names])
to be type independent

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if this worked (`<f4`, I mean), because it won't convert to the new type, merely reinterpret.

Comment: Thanks chthonicdaemon! I though I was getting nuts because I tried to use the np.core.records.fromarrays which copies all the data for nothing... Do you know how can avoid telling explicitly the data type ('f4') so it will keep it as it was?

Comment: I think the option sega_sai suggested is the best way to do it if you want to keep the types of the original array. I've edited the answer.

Comment: The x.dtype does NOT work due to the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<debug input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<debug input>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Comment: this works: (lambda names=names, t=x.dtype: [(n, t) for n in names])()

Comment: Hanan, that error makes it appear as though you do not have x in the scope where you are calling the code. x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)]);
names = ['a','b']; x.dtype = np.dtype([(n, x.dtype) for n in names]) works perfectly for me. I cannot understand why wrapping the reference in a lambda would make the problem go away, though.